# angular ionic, how to reload controller on link in the markup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to reload the controller I'm linking to in a menu in an ionic angular app.  How do I declare the link in the markup so that it refreshes the destination route every time the link is clicked?

I saw this bit of code

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
```

Which I suppose I can wrap in a controller method but I would prefer to do it in the markup if possible.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in the view? Basically you can have a method on the controller that takes the statename and pass statename from the view right? There is this `ui-sref = statename(paramObj)` but it wont reload unless param is different. Another way is to put `$state` as a property on scope in your controller (or controller instance is using controller As) and use it in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a function in your controller:

```
$scope.reload = function () {

    $state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: true });
}
```

Then use it in your view:

```
<button ng-click="reload()">Reload</button>
```